# aggregate: how to compute a blockwise maximum *and* retrieve some additional information about the maximum?

Tags: r

I have a data set with three pieces of information: time, type, value. For each
time point, I would like to know the maximal value (see (*)), but also the
corresponding type of the maximum. I know how to use aggregate to get the
maximal value for each time point, but how to get the corresponding type?

```
x <- data.frame(time=c(rep(1:2, 2), rep(2:1, 2)), type=LETTERS[1:4], value=1:8)
aggregate(value ~ time, data=x, FUN=max) # (*) ... but what is the corresponding type?
```

If possible, I am looking for a solution based on `aggregate()`, `tapply()` or the like (not requiring additional packages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`merge` should be able to handle this for you:

```
merge(x, aggregate(value ~ time, data=x, FUN=max))
#   time value type
# 1    1     8    D
# 2    2     7    C
```